# Differences in how Outlook 2007 and 2010 work with custom views?

Tags: .net, outlook, mapi

I have a custom view for an outlook plugin written in C# - in Outlook 2010 I am able to display all of the additional information I attach to an IMessage... In 2007, the extra columns are in place in the view, but the values from the IMessages are not populated into that column (Even though outlookSPY shows them to be on the IMessage object).

Does anyone here know why the behavior might be different?

Thanks

Comment: Does your view hardcode the named property tags? How exactly are the columns added to the view?

Comment: I am adding the properties via XML - As follows :

`code
    <column>
        <heading>Test Column</heading>
        <prop>http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{my guid property}/project/0x0000001F</prop>
        <type>string</type>
        <width>234</width>
        <style>padding-left:3px;;text-align:left</style>
        <editable>0</editable>
    </column>`

Comment: Also, apologies for the terrible formatting of the XML, I am not familiar with the formatting here.

Comment: That should be fine. When you look at a message that contains the data that is supposed to be visible in the view but is not, do you see the same DASL property name for that property containing the data (in OutlookSpy, click IMessage, select the property in question, look at the DASL edit box)?

Comment: Thanks for getting in touch... the property in DASL is the one below. It seems to match up.

http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{my guid property}/project.property/0x0000001F

Comment: Hmmm... I don't know. Can you modify the view manually through Outlook UI?